# How to retrieve a resource from within a tWebModule

Tags: delphi

I am trying to extract a gif image embedded as a resource within my ISAPI dll using WebBroker technology.  The resource has been added to the DLL using the following RC code:

```
LOGO_GIF RCDATA logo.gif
```

Using resource explorer I verified it is in the DLL properly.

using the following code always throws an exception, "resource not found" (using Delphi 2009)

```
var
  rc : tResourceStream;
begin
  rc := tResourceStream.Create(hInstance,'LOGO_GIF','RCDATA');
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RCDATA is a [pre-defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381039(VS.85).aspx) resource type with an integer ID of RT_RCDATA (declared in Types unit).

Try accessing it this way:

```
rc := tResourceStream.Create(hInstance,'LOGO_GIF', MakeIntResource(RT_RCDATA));
```

Comment: you don't need the MakeIntResource at all

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you are actually dealing with an instance of the web server, not the dll.  I don't remember the work around though, but that is the explanation for why that doesn't work.  Hopefully someone else can build off of this.

Answer (score 1):

Either use your own arbitrary resource type like GIF:

```
LOGO_GIF GIF logo.gif
```

then use

```
rc := tResourceStream.Create(hInstance,'LOGO_GIF','GIF');
```

or simply use

```
rc := tResourceStream.Create(hInstance,'LOGO_GIF', RT_RCDATA);
```

Answer (score 1):

> or simply use
>
> rc := tResourceStream.Create(hInstance,'LOGO_GIF', **RT__RCDATA**);

This. Works like a charm.

D2009 here, too, had the same issue, but was trying to get TStringsList out of the DLL.

Thanks.